# MySQL - A difficult INSERT...SELECT on the same table [MySQL 5.051]

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a new row into my table which holds the same data as the one I am trying to select from the same table but with a different `user_id` and without a fixed value for `auto_id` since that is an auto_increment field, and setting `ti` to NOW(). Below is my mockup query where '1' is the new `user_id`. I have been trying many variations but am still stuck, anyone who can help me with turning this into a working query.

```
INSERT INTO `lins` ( `user_id` , `ad` , `ke` , `se` , `la` , `ra` , `ty` , `en` , `si` , `mo` , `ti` , `de` , `re` , `ti` ) (

SELECT '1', `ad` , `ke` , `se` , `la` , `ra` , `ty` , `en` , `si` , `mo` , `ti` , `de` , `re` , NOW( )
FROM `lins`
WHERE autoid = '4'
AND user_id = '2'
)
```

Thank you for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'ke' in 'field list'

However the column is definitly present in the table.

Comment: Could you post the DDL of your table so that it would be easier to try your query out to figure out what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it, and it works for me.

Did you misspell the column name corresponding to "`ke`"?

I'm guessing the actual column names in your table are not just two letters.  E.g. you have two columns named "`ti`" in the query you show, so I assume you have edited these down from longer names.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you know that "WHERE autoid = 4" is sufficient if it's a unique autoid. And if you intended to single-quote the integers (1, 4 and 2), and they're numeric, you've created implied casts; in the WHERE clause, that will disable the ability of the optimizer to use indexes on the resulting integer values.

Also, using unnecessary (and easily mistyped) back-ticks has been the root of at least one other similar question here.