# Select and insert into a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

Mysql table

```
create table table1(
   id int(3) zerofill auto_increment primary key,
   username varchar(10)
)
engine=innodb;
```

Mysql insert query

```
insert into table1 (username)
       select id from (select id from table1) as a where 
         a.id=last_insert_id();
```

I am trying to insert into a table by selecting the last id from the same table and the same row,the above queries give the explanation of what i want to do.The insert query gives null value in both the id and username.
The expected results is below.

```
id        username
001         001
002         002
003         003
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292851/mysql-a-difficult-insert-select-on-the-same-table-mysql-5-051?rq=1  this link may help you

Comment: Why are you doing this: `select id from (select id from table1) as a where a.id=last_insert_id()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (username)
SELECT LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1, 3, '0')
  FROM table1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acc45/1)** demo

A drawback of this approach is that under heavy load different concurrent users may get the same `MAX(id)` and you'll end up with rows that have different ids but the same username.

---

Now, the more precise way to do it involves a separate sequencing table and a `BEFORE INSERT` triger

Proposed changed table schema

```
CREATE TABLE table1_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE table1
(
   id INT(3) ZEROFILL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0,
   username VARCHAR(10)
);
```

The trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table1_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1_seq VALUES(NULL);
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID(), NEW.username = LPAD(NEW.id, 3, '0');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now you just insert new rows into `table1` like this

```
INSERT INTO table1 (username) 
VALUES (NULL), (NULL)
```

Outcome:

```
| ID | USERNAME |
-----------------
|  1 |      001 |
|  2 |      002 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36a36/1)** demo

Comment: @George You're very welcome. I'm glad I could help :) See updated answer for another more precise approach.

Comment: Thanks peterm,I am grateful.They are both precise and beautiful.Thanks.But please before I let you go,is it possible to create two triggers on one table?Thanks

Comment: @George You can only one trigger per event and operation. Meaning you can only one `BEFORE INSERT` and only one `AFTER INSERT` trigger  etc. But you can always accommodate a trigger's logic to support all possible (which is allowed by MySql) processing.

Comment: @peterm.Thanks for time

Comment: @peterm.Please see this question and try if you could help  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/q/18091831/2595059).Thanks

Comment: Thanks Once more genius for you rescue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34951/discussion-between-george-and-peterm)

Comment: Hello peterm, can you please invite me to a chat room, so we could chat.Thank you

Comment: Hello Mr. Peterm, pls i have a question on database design, i have posted it in database administrators, can you pls help me.Thanks.This is the link to the question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/62099/26129

Answer (score 1):

Why store the value at all?

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   id int(3) zerofill auto_increment PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE VIEW oh_look_username
  AS
SELECT id
     , LPad(Cast(id As varchar(10)), 3, '0') As username
FROM   table1
```