# insert by selecting values from two columns into a column from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Please I am inserting values by selecting two values from two columns into one column in the same table.Below are my queries.

```
create table table1(
 id int(3) zerofill auto_increment primary key,
 prefix varchar(10) default "AB",
 username varchar(10)
)
engine=innodb;
```

Mysql insert query

```
 insert into table1 (username) 
 select prefix + (LPAD(Coalesce(MAX(id),0) + 1,3, '0'))
  from table1;
```

The above insert query does not work,it gives null in the username column,please any help is appreciated.Thanks.
The expected results is below.

```
   id    Prefix   username
   001    AB       AB001
   002    AB       AB002
   003    AB       AB003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

1. As Matt mentioned you need to use `CONCAT()` in MySql
2. For the first record being inserted your SELECT returns `NULL` therefore you need to use `COALESCE()` or `IFNULL()` to get DEFAULT value for concatenation

Your query should look like this

```
INSERT INTO table1 (username)
SELECT CONCAT(COALESCE(prefix, 'AB'), LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1, 3, '0'))
  FROM table1
```

Outcome:

```
| ID | PREFIX | USERNAME |
--------------------------
|  1 |     AB |    AB001 |
|  2 |     AB |    AB002 |
```

Here is **[SQLFddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30bc9/1)**

Comment: I want to prevent the CONSTANT `AB` in the query and allow it to call the 'AB' from the table1.Something like this, `SELECT CONCAT(COALESCE(prefix, ''), LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1, 3, '0'))
  FROM table1`,is it possible or there is a different way out,thanks

Comment: @George The query gets the prefix from the table, and a constant value is used only if there is no rows in the table (table is empty and you are trying to insert the first row). In that case prefix is `NULL` and  thats why `COALESCE` is used to picks `'AB'` from the second parameter.

Comment: Please can we chat now,I mean in the chat room

Comment: I am using different tables with different default prefix,that is why i want to prevent the constant 'AB' in the query,so that I could use one query for all the tables.

Answer (score 2):

`+` is not the string concatenation operator in MySQL. If you're using [`sql_mode=PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) (or [equivalent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi)), then:

```
insert into table1 (username) 
select prefix || (LPAD(Coalesce(MAX(id),0) + 1,3, '0'))
from table1;
```

otherwise use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).